# Any way to use my own custom fonts in adobe flash cs6?

Tags: flash, fonts, adobe, embedding

I cannot find this anywhere on the internet. Is there a way to add my own fonts or downloaded fonts to my flash project using adobe flash cs6? The only thing showing up on internet searches are embedding fonts, but it won't let me actually use fonts that aren't naturally a part of their list.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can embed any font you have the file to.

see: http://inspiritgames.com/blog/2010/09/embed-fonts-into-pure-as3-project/

Something like:

```
[Embed(source="pathToTtfFile", fontName="FontName", mimeType="application/x-font- truetype")]
```

should allow you to use FontName after execution as long as you put the font file in pathToTtfFile

Also, you should actually be able to embed any font you have installed on your system through the embed option in the designer as well. As soon as you install it, it should appear in the list of Font families.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I had turned out to be that I didnt save my fonts in my fonts folder. As soon as I set it in there (installed it) I was finally able to embed properly.